# HTML5 : Create File object from <img>

Tags: html, html5-filesystem

Is it possible to create a `File object (HTML5)` from an `<img src=".." />` tag ?

Comment: You might be able to if it is on the same server otherwise you might have a CORs issue. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/9490022/382536 and comments